# Using macro with optional argument inside macro with optional argument

Tags: math-mode, macros, optional-arguments

I am trying to define a macro that has an optional argument that can take a macro with an optional argument as an argument. A minimal example to explain the problem more clearly:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\inn}[1][a]{#1}
\newcommand*{\out}[1][\inn]{\underline{#1}}
% \newcommand*{\out}[1][\inn]{\underline{#1}} % this also doesn't work (1)
% \newcommand*{\out}[1][\inn]{{#1}} % this also doesn't work (2)

\begin{document}
  $\out[\inn[b]]$
%  $\out[{\inn[b]}]$ % this works (3)
\end{document}
```

I get the error `! Argument of \\inn has an extra }`. As indicated, I can fix the issue on a case-by-case basis, but not in general (using the right definition of the macros).

I first thought this was an issue caused by `\underline` being fragile. But using `\ensuremath` or `\protected` didn't lead me to a solution.

How can I fix the macros, so that they do what I want without errors?

Comment: It is due to how LaTeX parses the optional argument, it stops at the first `]`, so you need to use the commented syntax when there is an optional argument here.

Comment: As Andrew Swann wrote: Grouping with `{ }` is necessary. This is not really tedious.

Comment: I am working on a fork of a document that should be merged back into the master with minimal change, so adding groupings is not an option. I am really looking for a macro-based-fix and I am unconvinced this is impossible in principle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The LaTeX2e approach to grabbing optional arguments uses a TeX delimited macro, which comes down to looking for an opening `[` then using a macro which is defined in the form

```
\def\foo[#1]{...
```

That will always grab the first `]` rather than do bracket matching. It is of course possible to match brackets. That is probably easiest to do using [`xparse`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse) as it is built-in

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand\inn{O{a}}{#1}
\NewDocumentCommand\out{O{\inn}}{\underline{#1}}

\begin{document}
  $\out[\inn[b]]$
\end{document}
```

Note that commands defined using `xparse` are declared using a different syntax to that uses by `\newcommand`. Here, an optional argument is type `O` with the default given as an argument to that `O`.

Comment: Oh, just saw you answered too

Answer (score 7):

If you are open to `xparse` and its `\NewDocumentCommand`, the nesting of optional arguments without additional `{}` is possible.

The syntax of `\NewDocumentCommand` is different to `\newcommand` and for beginners a little bit confusing, but I switched lately to it and won't miss it any longer. I recommend `xparse` and its macros as long as no expansion is required (apart from the `\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand` feature)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\newcommand*{\inn}[1][a]{#1}
\newcommand*{\out}[1][{\inn}]{\underline{#1}}
% \newcommand*{\out}[1][\inn]{\underline{#1}} % this also doesn't work
% \newcommand*{\out}[1][\inn]{{#1}} % this also doesn't work

\NewDocumentCommand{\Inn}{O{a}}{%
#1%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\Out}{O{\Inn}}{%
\underline{#1}%
}


\begin{document}
\out[{\inn[b]}] % original version
  \Out[\Inn[b]] % Double []
  \Out[\Inn]
\end{document}
```